# Unable to View Content of the Document Library in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, ms-office, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I am the site collection administrator of one application. One specific user cannot able to see the content of the document library. He is provided with the full control over the site as well as that specific document library. He is able to access the document library but cannot see the contents in it. All other users able to view the contents.

Please suggest me some solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if library items have item level permission configured.

Comment: But the user has "Full Control" permission to the items in the Document Library.

Comment: Permissions can be assigned one to the whole library and another to just the item also. I think it makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks nixcom.. IT works..!!! He don't have permission to the contents. That user has permission to the Document Library only.

Comment: Care to explain how to do that in Sharepoint online? I don't know how to access content level permissions. I have a folder full of other folders that are full of files.